# How to uninstall flux on linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, uninstall, f.lux

Flux is a lighting app which malfunctions on my laptop. I tried

```
sudo apt-get remove flux
```

in the terminal, but it responds with "the package doesn't exist".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To uninstall f.lux, you need to do this:

`sudo apt-get remove fluxgui`

Comment: Also worth noting that you can use `dpkg-query --list | grep flux` to find an actual package name, if you've forgotten it.

Answer (score 4):

To uninstall:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/{fluxgui/,f.lux_indicator*}
sudo rm /usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/fluxgui.* 
sudo rm /usr/local/share/applications/fluxgui.desktop
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/{xflux,fluxgui}
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/fluxgui/
```

sudo is used to become root, your password will be asked the first time.

Comment: Not recommended - should always use the package manager for uninstallation for consistency, ideally.

Answer (score 2):

Type

```
sudo apt-get remove
```

and partial app name
and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  It will automatically fill the name of the application you want to remove.